# Geometry question on with two circles from BMO1 1994

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I am preparing for the BMO1 this year and found this geometry question 4 on the [1994 paper](https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo1-1994.pdf).

> The points Q, R lie on the circle γ, and P is a point such that PQ, PR are tangents to γ. A
> is a point on the extension of PQ, and γ′ is the circumcircle of triangle PAR. The circle γ′ cuts γ again at B, and AR cuts γ at the point C. Prove that angle PAR = angle ABC.

I drew additional line segments PB and BR in γ′ to get the cyclic quadrilateral APBR and then drew BQ and BC in γ to get the cyclic quadrilateral QBRC. Then I did a lot of angle chasing using the tangent alternate segment circle theorem and found that triangle BPQ is similar to BQC and also triangle PAB is similar to BRC.

From here, I can't find a way to proceed. Please can someone give me a hint on what my next step should be (preferably a geometric solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck for the BMO this year! This should be a matter of using the alternate segment theorem, the theorem that opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral are supplementary (twice), and that the triangle $PQR$ is isosceles because $PQ$ and $PR$ are tangents from the same external point, and chasing angles.

Diagram:

[image]

1: $\angle PAR = 180^{\circ} - \angle AQC - \angle QCA$ (angles sum to $180^{\circ}$ in a triangle)

2: $\angle QCA = 180^{\circ} - \angle QCR$ (angles on a straight line sum to $180^{\circ}$)

3: $\angle PAR = \angle QCR - \angle AQC$ (substituting line 2 into line 1)

4: $\angle AQC = 180^{\circ} - \angle RQC - \angle PQR$ (angles on a straight line sum to $180^{\circ}$)

5: $\angle PQR = \angle QCR$ (alternate segment theorem)

6: $\angle AQC = 180^{\circ} - \angle RQC - \angle QCR$ (substituting line 5 into line 4)

7: $\angle PAR = 2\angle QCR - 180^{\circ} + \angle RQC $ (substituting line 6 into line 3)

8: $\angle PAR = 2 \angle PQR - 180^{\circ} + \angle RQC$ (substituting line 5 into line 7)

9: $\angle QPR = 180^{\circ} - 2 \angle PQR$ (tangents from the same external point)

10: $\angle PAR = \angle RQC - \angle QPR$ (substituting line 9 into line 8)

11: $\angle RQC = 180^{\circ} - \angle CBR$ (opposite angles in the cyclic quadrilateral $QRBC$ add to $180^{\circ}$)

12: $\angle PAR = 180^{\circ} - \angle CBR - \angle QPR$ (substituting line 11 into line 10)

13: $\angle QPR = 180^{\circ} - (\angle CBR + \angle ABC) $ (opposite angles in the cyclic quadrilateral $PABR$ add to $180^{\circ}$)

14: $\angle PAR = \angle ABC$ (substituting line 13 into line 12)

Comment: Thank you, How did you get --- 2: ∠QCA=180∘−∠QRC
 (angles on a straight line sum to 180∘
) --- ?

Comment: It should have been $\angle QCR$ not $\angle QRC$! I've edited the post now

Comment: In my diagram A, R and C are collinear, so doesn't that mean ∠QCA = ∠QCR, rather than ∠QCA = 180 - ∠QCR ?

Comment: I've added a diagram to my answer, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. In my diagram $A$ was on the opposite side of $P$ from $Q$. In the olympiad, will it affect my marks which diagram I draw?

Comment: In general you should definitely consider all the possible diagrams for the BMO. I think there is one other interesting case (A is between P and Q). If P is between Q and A that is a pretty degenerate case where AR does not cut $\gamma$ (unless you say $R=C$ but then there's a quick proof).